# Entity Framework Core is significantly slower for delete query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am deleting a row on the basis of primary using EF Core and it takes more than 1 second to execute, while otherwise simply creating a command a deleting only takes around 400 ms.

I am using a Mysql database.

It takes just 140 ms to delete a row using Mysql directly.

Why is EF so slow ?

```
using (DBContex db = new DbContext())
{
    var revenueModel = db.Revenue.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (revenueModel != null)
    {
        db.MSRevenues.Remove(revenueModel);
        result = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give us the Explain plan for both in order for us to tell why it's slow. Also the index definitions

Comment: You are getting the item out of the database, checking if it exists, then deleting it. 2 trips to the db. Do the same with a command and then compare. If you eliminate one trip, it will be faster.

Comment: Plus the time EF needs to build the model if this is a "cold start". Anyway, yes, the comparison isn't fair.

Comment: And 140ms is an awefully long time to delete a single row.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft what should be the realistic time for single row using PK ?

Comment: You're asking questions we can't answer without enough background info. If there are many foreign keys referring to this table deletion may take "much" time. We don't know the database/class model, we don't know if this is a cold start, or the EF version.

Answer (score 2):

EF Core is designed to modify database only via Change Tracker. This design makes life easier but slowdown simple operations. Usually you have to select entity, make modification/delete and `SaveChanges`. This is two database roundtrips, plus time for query translation.

Anyway, for such simple case, you can remove one roundtrip by just simple trick:

```cs
_context.MSRevenues.Remove(new MSRevenue() { Id = id });
result = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: This is sometimes called a "stub entity".

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I tried and now the response is better than before almost around 900ms but still more than plain sql command.

Comment: EF can't be as fast as sql command.... they create some roundtrip for generate query, for tracking entities and so on.....